# Why code Error appear only on Iphone Opera?

Tags: javascript, safari, shopify

Today I encountered a very strange problem  during some debugging.

We are currently creating a Theme for Shopify and one of your JS file create a Cart popup (Based from another JS pluging found in github).
In this file a Error modale will pop up in case of probleme.

Due to customer currency we need to write the item price from this 10000 to this 10,000

So I added this line to do the conversion :

```
 var formatPrice = formatPrice.toString().match(/.{3}/g).join(',');
```

It work on ALL browser , exepte Iphone 12 mini Safari...It give the Modal error.
Any idea , why this happen ?

The project is very big so its difficult for me to share wider code :/

Answer (score 0):

Found It ! Safari is the only browser to not Support : toString() function.
Gonna find an alternative ;)

Comment: Safari supports toString() https://caniuse.com/?search=toString()